# Regex Generation for a string pattern to replace space

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a string query which looks like:
((data.field:ankit OR data.country:New Zealand) AND data.operator:Shell Ops Ltd) OR arch session

I am creating a regex which which will replace all spaces with %20 except around "AND" and "OR".

I tried pattern matching but it didn't work. I also tried pattern for not including ' OR ' or ' AND '.

Is there a way with RexEx which can help me identify spaces apart from around OR and AND.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use look ahead and look behind expressions to find the spaces:

```
(?<!AND)(?<!OR)\s+(?!AND)(?!OR)
```

<sup>Interactive example on https://regex101.com/r/0XMigJ/1</sup>

Your script then is:

```js
const query = "((data.field:ankit OR data.country:New Zealand) AND data.operator:Shell Ops Ltd) OR arch session";
const reg = /(?<!AND)(?<!OR)\s+(?!AND)(?!OR)/g

console.log(query.replace(reg, "%20"));
```

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly. I am now learning about look ahead and look behind expressions.